# .NET Code refactorings, what is your best practice?

Tags: .net, refactoring

What are your .NET code-refactoring best practices?

Comment: Can you elaborate your intent behind the q? As it stands: My best practice would be to "Do it."

Comment: Yes, and make sure that what you end up with is better than what you started with ;0)

Comment: I really need to know what is best practices while doing code refactoring?

Comment: What do you actually want to know? Common smells? Anti-patterns? Refactoring tools? Your question is very vague.

Comment: What are points to be focused while doing code refactoring?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Refactoring Best Practice Rule  No.1:** Write some tests first!

Refactoring should make code easier to maintain, and ideally reduce coupling between components/classes.

Good candidates for refactoring are classes with high-coupling to other classes, and classes that do too much (breaking the Single Responsibility Principle)

Tools like [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) or [Visual Studio's built-in tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379618(VS.80).aspx) are useful aids.

If you are using VB.NET then check out: [Refactor! for Visual Basic 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb693327.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Usually **writing tests is not the first thing you do**, with legacy code most likely you'll not be able to write tests (dependencies on db, external libraries, statics, and so on)

**Lean on the tools first**, use automatic refactorings like 'Extract method' (Resharper and VS are your friends)

Working Effectively with Legacy Code by Michael Feathers is a very good book to learn how to break those dependencies.

For numeric algorithms and parsers PEX is a very useful tool to easily create characterization unit tests.

Comment: Aha. First thing i do - increase readability with small changes which doesn't change any functionality.

Comment: @Arnis L.: The problem is always, "How can I be sure my trivial chnages didn't chnage/break anything?". I know from experience(!) that even the smallest changes can sometimes have unintended consequences.

Comment: @Mitch If you lean to tools first you can be 99% sure that you want brake anything. Next thing to do is of course write some tests.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend actually reading the book. "[Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201485672)", by Martin Fowler.

Answer (score 2):

As vague as the quesion is, it is hard to give any good answer. But I suggest you read Martin Fowler's catalog of refactorings, it gives you an excellent starting point:

> [**Refactorings**](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Don't mix refactoring with adding or changing functionality of the application.

Answer (score 0):

- Your code should be more readable/understandable not less when you are done.
- Generally your methods should become shorter, not longer.
- Repetitive code should be moved into it's own method and reused.

Answer (score 0):

Refactor with a suite of tests to ensure you aren't breaking anything.

Answer (score 0):

Save your source code in a sourcecontrol system .. and when the refactoring fails just reset the current branch. That way you can never do any harm ... except waste some time occasionally. It's pretty cool since you can just hack & slash away at your code without worrying it'll never work again.

Also, when it's easy to do it on a new branch, do so. You never know when a bug creeps up halfway your refactoring process and you have to roll out a patch quickly (based on the previous, stable version).

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion, keep note of specific ways you want or need to refactor and stick them in a wiki or document someplace, because later down the road you might not have the luxury of time to spend rethinking what you were going to do to improve or otherwise overhaul the code.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all code repetition.